# Devstack installation error : CryptographyDeprecationwarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead

Tags: python, linux, cryptography, devstack

Hello I am trying to install devstack on ubuntu 20.04 and I keep getting error

Cryptographydepricationwarning : int_from_bytes is deprecated use int.from_bytes instead

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

[CryptographyDepricationWarning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S472F.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you need to pin an older version of cryptography, e.g. cryptography<3.4, that will satisfy SecretStorage's dependency and not throw deprecation warnings.
That means you should install cryptography<3.4 into your environment, and this version of cryptography should be picked up.

To Do so:

```
pip freeze | grep "cryptography"  #show current version of cryptography
sudo pip uninstall cryptography   #uninstall it
sudo pip install cryptography==3.3 #install new version <3.4 (here I chose 3.3)
```

I referred to [this](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/issues/9454) similar issue